# Why my rxjs combineLatest output only 2 times?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Consider the following rxjs@5.5.11 code:

```js
{
  const source1 = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3);
  const source2 = Rx.Observable.of(4, 5);

  const combined = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(source1, source2);

  const subscribe = combined.subscribe(([value1, value2]) => {
    console.log(`value1 Latest: ${value1}`);
    console.log(`value2 Latest: ${value2}`);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.11/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

I imagined this result would be something like this:

(emit 1 time and gives lasted)

```
value1 Latest: 3
value2 Latest: 5
```

or

(emit 3 times and gives lasted from each)

```
value1 Latest: 1
value2 Latest: 4
value1 Latest: 2
value2 Latest: 5
value1 Latest: 3
value2 Latest: 5
```

but actually it is:

(emit 2 times and gives lasted from each)

```
value1 Latest: 3
value2 Latest: 4
value1 Latest: 3
value2 Latest: 5
```

Why?

Comment: https://staltz.com/primer-on-rxjs-schedulers.html

Answer (score 4):

Neither of these observables have any delay. As soon as you subscribe, `source1` will instantly emit all of the values `1, 2, 3`. And then it subscribes to `source2` and each of the values that it emits are combined with the latest value, `3`, from `source1`.

Adding a tiny delay between each value will force each event to be emitted in sequence. React will even respect a zero delay to enforce this ordering. The result is that it will alternately take one event from each:

```
{
  const source1 = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
    .zip(Rx.Observable.timer(0, 0), (x, _) => x);

  const source2 = Rx.Observable.of(4, 5)
    .zip(Rx.Observable.timer(0, 0), (x, _) => x);

  const combined = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(source1, source2);

  const subscribe = combined.subscribe(([value1, value2]) => {
    console.log(`value1 Latest: ${value1}`);
    console.log(`value2 Latest: ${value2}`);
  });
}
```

```
value1 Latest: 1
value2 Latest: 4
value1 Latest: 2
value2 Latest: 4
value1 Latest: 2
value2 Latest: 5
value1 Latest: 3
value2 Latest: 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Visual explanation may be good here. The reason may be your first and second observables emitted something like the following:

```
First observable:  -----1------2------3
Second observable: -----------------------4-----5
Result:            ---------------------[3,4]--[3,5]
```

Please note that the `combineLatest` will wait till both observables emit values.

Comment: Wrong. `.zip()` will wait for both observables to emit, whereas `.combineLatest()` will emit an item whenever any of the source Observables emits an item. Docs: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

Comment: @CozyAzure Carefully read the phrase in the link that you mentioned above: "...so long as each of the source Observables has emitted at least one item...". This means combineLatest should wait till each of the source Observables has emitted at least one item.

Comment: Does an operator exist that will emit as soon as any source observable emits?

Comment: @ZackDeRose: quick fix = a startWith() on every observable in your combineLatest